# How do I whitelist a domain in iOS restrictions web filter?

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, parental-controls

Turning on iOS restrictions (Settings - General - Restrictions) and the web filter inside (probably "Websites - Restrict adult content" or something similar in English), I tried whitelisting `wikipedia.org` but the whitelist doesn't seem to work. For instance, the page "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control" is still blocked.

I tried whitelisting `*.wikipedia.org/*`. It still doesn't work, and I can't find any instructions on how to format the entries.

*How do I exclude a specific domain from being filtered?*

With respect, **please refrain from** non-answers such as "just turn off restrictions" or suggesting unrealistic solutions like "you have to enter every possible subdomain by hand without using wildcards".

*Iphone 5 running Ios 8.4*

Comment: Please provide more detail on where in settings you are enabling and attempting to whitelist.  I tried to follow along and see if I could figure it out, but I can't find the settings section you are working with.

Comment: @Tyson I added the path to restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Andreas, he recently tried it again and it works fine now. But here's a somehwhat comprehensive answer anyways:

There are two ways to whitelist a website:

1. **From Safari:** When you try to access a website and it gets blocked, tap "Allow Access" and then the restrictions passcode.
2. **From Settings:** Go to *Settings* > *General* > *Restrictions* > *Enter the passcode*. Then go to the *Safari* settings. There, add your website to "*Always allow*" list. In your case, adding "wikipedia.org" would be enough.

Unfortunately, there are no ways to add wildcards like "*.google.*", which is what I need and why I ended up here.

**Note**: If the website you are trying to whitelist is in the *Never Allow* list, then remove first from that list. Otherwise whatever you do, that website will still get blocked since the *Never Allow* list trumps the *Always Allow* list.

**About Domains and Subdomains:**
Domains trump subdomains. In other words, if *apple.com* is on the blacklist, all subdomains, like *developer.apple.com* for example, will also be blocked.

On the other hand, if *developer.apple.com* is on the blacklist, but not *apple.com*, then only the former will be blocked and the latter would still be accessible.

Note: If there are screen time limitations (app limits) in effect, you may also have to add the whitelisted domains and sub-domains to the specific screen time limit - go to 'websites' at the bottom of the list and tick the circles against the permitted domains.

Comment: To quote myself: "I tried whitelisting wikipedia.org". Could you summarize why doing this would now work? Which version of iOS are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. It works on iOS 7 or later. Maybe you had wikipedia.org in the Never Allow list? This list trumps the Always Allow list. I'll add this note to the answer.

Comment: I just tried this out and can confirm that it works now. However I'm pretty sure I didn't mistakenly put Wikipedia on the blacklist last time I tried this, so if this works in iOS 7 as you say then I suspect Apple has pushed new filter rules to devices. Could you shift focus to *domains and subdomains* in your answer, as well as underline the fact that what I tried in the question now actually works? Then I'll accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer.